# Second order differential inequality and comparison theorem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $x:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R, x \in C^{\infty}$ that satisfies
$$\begin{cases} \ddot{x} \leq -2x \\ x(0) = x(1) = 0  \end{cases}$$
is it true that $x \geq 0$ on $[0,1]$?

I observed that if $x \geq 0$, then $\ddot x \leq0 $, so $x$ is concave. However I could not find out any other properties. I think if there exists a solution of the following differential equation
$$ \begin{cases} \ddot{x} = -2x \\ x(0) = x(1) = 0  \end{cases} $$
then some kind of comparative theorem can be used. However, there is no non-trivial solution for this.

If the above proposition is incorrect, could you give me a counterexample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concavity is enough: $x(t) = x((1 - t)\cdot 0 + t \cdot 1) \geq (1 - t) \cdot x(0) + t \cdot x(1) = 0$.

Alternatively, by Rolle's theorem, $x'(t_0) = 0$ for some $t_0 \in (0, 1)$, and as $x'' \leq 0$, $x'(t) \geq 0$ if $t < t_0$ and $x'(t) \leq 0$ if $t > t_0$, so $x$ not decreases on $[0, t_0]$ - thus is non-negative there, and $x$ not increases on $[t_0, 1]$ - thus again is non-negative there.